# Gunicorn is listening TCP port instead of unix socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, gunicorn, supervisord

When I run the gunicorn in project directory like this:

```
/home/dmitry/.virtualenv/my_env/bin/gunicorn videotube.wsgi:application -c /path/to/project/settings/gunicorn/production.py
```

everything is fine:

```
2014-07-31 14:03:12 [2940] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/tonna-porno.com.sock (2940)
```

But if I do the same thing using `supervisor` (here's the configuration file):

```
[program:project_name]

command=/home/dmitry/.virtualenv/my_env/bin/gunicorn videotube.wsgi:application -c /path/to/project/settings/gunicorn/production.py
directory=/path/to/project
user=dmitry
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/dmitry/logs/project_name/errors.log
stdout_logfile=/home/dmitry/logs/project_name/access.log
```

I can see in logs:

```
2014-07-31 13:48:48 [2776] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (2776)
```

I have even tried to put socket address right to the command:

```
command="/home/dmitry/.virtualenv/tonna_porno/bin/gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/mysock.com.sock videotube.wsgi:application"
```

but gunicorn still listens the TCP port.